Entity not rendering after moving using EntityCommandBuffer in Unity DOTS
I am new to Unity DOTS and for a starter project, I want to move some ship entities given the speed and direction. This is my system:
namespace Obscure.SpaceShooter
{
    [BurstCompile]
    public partial struct ShipMovementSystem : ISystem
    {
        [BurstCompile]
        public void OnUpdate(ref SystemState state)
        {
            Debug.Log("OnUpdate");

            float deltaTime = SystemAPI.Time.DeltaTime;
            var ecbSingleton = SystemAPI.GetSingleton<BeginSimulationEntityCommandBufferSystem.Singleton>();

            new ShipMovementJob{
                deltaTime = deltaTime,
                entityCommandBuffer = ecbSingleton.CreateCommandBuffer(state.WorldUnmanaged)
            }.Schedule(); // same issue with Run()
        }
    }

    [BurstCompile]
    public partial struct ShipMovementJob : IJobEntity
    {
        public float deltaTime;
        public EntityCommandBuffer entityCommandBuffer;

        [BurstCompile]
        public void Execute(ShipAspect shipAspect)
        {
            float2 moveVector = shipAspect.movement.ValueRO.direction * shipAspect.movement.ValueRO.speed;
            float3 newPosition = shipAspect.transform.ValueRO.Position + new float3(moveVector.x, moveVector.y, 0) * deltaTime;

            Debug.Log($"Moving ship {shipAspect.entity.Index} to {newPosition} from {shipAspect.transform.ValueRO.Position}");

            entityCommandBuffer.SetComponent(shipAspect.entity, new LocalTransform
            {
                Position = newPosition
            });
        }
    }
}

In the scene the ship doesn't move, but in the entity inspector, their position changes. I used Debug.Log and the values match:



did you install entity graphics?

PS I didnt think you need a buffer unless you were instantiating or destroying items

I have installed Entity Graphics and removed the buffer, however I will destroy the ships when required. Is using EntityCommandBuffer necessary? For context, there will be > 1000 ships in a scene.

ECS has changed a lot - I mean a heck of a lot, and almost every time you look its changed again.  so tbh, i havent looked since 1.2.0 was a thing.. so, i am not sure, but i believe Id go with yes for destroys and instantiates as it was last time i tried :D but, documentation should answer that.

Right now I decided to not use ECBs, but maybe I will add them later.

Okay so I ended up not using the EntityCommandBuffer and it works now.
For anyone in the future, this is the final script, I also added input, and rotation with the help of a tutorial:
    [BurstCompile]
    public partial struct ShipMovementSystem : ISystem
    {
        [BurstCompile]
        public void OnUpdate(ref SystemState state)
        {
            float deltaTime = SystemAPI.Time.DeltaTime;

            new ShipMovementJob
            {
                deltaTime = deltaTime,
            }.Schedule();
        }
    }

    [BurstCompile]
    public partial struct ShipMovementJob : IJobEntity
    {
        public float deltaTime;

        [BurstCompile]
        public void Execute(ShipAspect shipAspect)
        {
            // Move the ship
            float2 moveVector = float2.zero;
            if (shipAspect.movement.ValueRO.isPlayer)
            {
                moveVector = shipAspect.inputsData.ValueRO.move * shipAspect.movement.ValueRO.speed;
            }
            float3 newPosition = shipAspect.transform.ValueRO.Position + new float3(moveVector.x, moveVector.y, 0) * deltaTime;

            shipAspect.transform.ValueRW.Position = newPosition;

            // Rotate the ship to face the direction of movement
            float rotationTime = shipAspect.movement.ValueRO.rotationTime;
            if (math.lengthsq(moveVector) > 0.01f)
            {
                float angle = math.atan2(-moveVector.x, moveVector.y);
                quaternion newRotation = quaternion.RotateZ(angle);
                // smooth rotation
                shipAspect.transform.ValueRW.Rotation = math.slerp(shipAspect.transform.ValueRO.Rotation, newRotation, rotationTime * deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                // smooth rotation
                shipAspect.transform.ValueRW.Rotation = math.slerp(shipAspect.transform.ValueRO.Rotation, quaternion.identity, rotationTime * deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }


This Inspector is showing Runtime values and values are changing - so your system works.
Entity is not moving however because an open subscene (open for authoring) causes the Editor to switch to render their authoring GameObjects instead of their runtime Entity.

Solution
Close all subscenes (untick that toggles☐ in Hierarchy window) before starting the game.
